# why does this selector work in chrome but not in scrapy?

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I am trying to scrape the stock name , its relevant news and time of news but scrapy doesn't return any output

```
class StationDetailSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'tone'
    start_urls = ["http://www.moneycontrol.com/india/stockpricequote/auto-lcvs-hcvs/ashokleyland/AL"]

    def parse_news(self, response):
        for brickset in response.css:
            #TIME_SELECTOR = '//div.gD_10 ::text'
            NAME_SELECTOR = './/div[@class='b_42h1[@class='b_42'] PT5 PR']'
            #NEWS_SELECTOR = '//a.bl_13 ::text'
            yield {
                #'time': brickset.css(TIME_SELECTOR).extract_first(),
                #'news': brickset.css(NEWS_SELECTOR).extract_first(),
                'name': brickset.xpath(NAME_SELECTOR).extract_first(),
                 }
```

any kind of insight would be greatly appreciated. I have tried other formats but in vain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your xpath seems incorrect and I am wondering what you did in Chrome to let it find something at all.

Try this xpath:

```
//div[@class="b_42 PT5 PR"]/h1/text()
```

Assuming you wish to scrape

> Ashok Leyland

Comment: sorry sir, but even this method doesn't work and there is no output.

Comment: ```>>> response.xpath('//div[@class="b_42 PT5 PR"]/h1/text()').extract_first()
u'Ashok Leyland'```

Comment: Showed you in my comment ^ that it outputs the name as stated in my answer

Comment: can you check the code other than my selector to see if there's a problem elsewhere as i have been at it or 3 days

Comment: sorry, It works now there was an error in my implementation

Answer (score 0):

In this particular case - there is only 1 `h1` tag so you can use the simple xpath of `//h1/text()`

Comment: I have already tried that and doesn't seem to produce any output.